# How do I direct links in popup-footnotes directly to main text?

Tags: epub, calibre, apple-books, footnotes

[image: example]Using calibre and epub3 I'm using popup footnotes (with epub:type). In some of the footnotes I present links (ex. a link to Chapter 2) to the main text. This referred text should not be presented in the popup windows itself (se right panel) - the links should direct to other chapters in the ebook (se left panel).

At the moment it seems that the referred text (ex. Chapter 2) are shown directly in the popup window (see right panel). How can I change this, so the links bypasses the popup window?

The problem occurs on a iMac in iBooks 1.16.

Regards, Dan

Comment: Which reading system are you designing for? iBooks? Kindle?

Comment: I have a little experience in this area, but I'm not 100% sure what you mean. Are you saying that the content of the footnote in the popup includes an internal link which does not work?

Comment: I am unable to tell whether your problem is specific to a reading system or just faulty code. Are you aware of the code example in  Section 9.3.12 (page 32) of the Kindle Publishing Guidelines? https://kindlegen.s3.amazonaws.com/AmazonKindlePublishingGuidelines.pdf

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Idiotprogrammer: Im using the coding presented in the guidelines and the footnote-popup itself works fine. My problem only concerns the result of the internal links.

Comment: (Actually this was what I was afraid you were going to say!) I've seen this problem before -- probably on iBooks. Unfortunately, iBooks is not well-documented and doesn't have a good community of formatters... ).

Answer (score 0):

First, one possible thing to look at is using the ASIDE element to contain the footnote. The Kindle way to do footnotes requires this.I used a DIV container which contained **epub:type="footnotes"** and inside that a ASIDE element containing what you want to be in the note. This is just a stab in the dark though.

Here's  a suggestion for a workaround on iBooks.

Perhaps iBooks only does this for internal links, but not for external links. The popup box fills with the internal HTML page you are linking to. This might be a feature, not a bug --- because letting  an HTML fragment appear in the popup is a cool thing though probably not part of the EPUB 3 spec.

Unfortunately I don't have an ipad handy now or I'd test and report back. But I vaguely remember seeing this before for footnotes on iBooks.

If you are linking to another place in the same ebook, why not just do an ordinary hyperlink in the main text and not a footnote? (If you need to add extra explanation, you can do it in the main text as well). It seems that providing an internal link from the popup is redundant. That's my two cents anyway.